# nvcc: Combine extern and constant

Tags: linker, cuda, nvcc

I would like to organise my CUDA code into separate object files to be linked at the end of compiling, as in C++. To that end I'd like to be able to declare an extern pointer to `__constant__` memory in a header file, and put the definition in one of the .cu files, also following the pattern from C++. But it seems that when I do so, nvcc ignores the 'extern' - it takes each declaration as a definition. Is there a way around this?

To be more specific about the code and the errors, I have this in a header file:

```
extern __device__ void* device_function_table[];
```

followed by this in a .cu file:

```
void* __device__ device_function_table[200];
```

which gives this error on compiling:

```
(path).cu:40: error: redefinition of ‘void* device_function_table [200]’
(path).hh:29: error: ‘void* device_function_table [200]’ previously declared here
```

My current solution is to use Makefile magic to glob together all my .cu files and have, in effect, one big translation unit but some semblance of file organisation. But this is already slowing down compiles noticeably, since a change to any one of my classes means recompiling all of them; and I anticipate adding several more classes.

Edit: I see I put `__constant__` in the text and `__device__` in the example; the question applies to both.

Comment: CUDA doesn't support separate compilation, so I wouldn't expect nvcc to handle ```extern __device__``` in any reasonable manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) version 4.0, section D.2.1.1:

> The `__device__` , `__shared__` and `__constant__` qualifiers are not allowed
>   on:
>
> - class, struct, and union data members,
> - formal parameters,
> - local variables within a function that executes on the host.
>
> `__shared__` and `__constant__` variables have implied static storage.
>
> `__device__` and `__constant__` variables are only allowed at file scope.
>
> `__device__`, `__shared__` and `__constant__` variables cannot be defined as  external using the extern keyword. The only exception is for dynamically allocated `__shared__` variables as described in Section B.2.3.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question even if it means I can't do what I was trying to do.

Comment: @RolfAndreassen, you can nowadays. See my answer below.

Comment: @Tom Perhaps time to update your answer for this to include separate compilation?

Answer (score 4):

Cutting the long story short, with recent CUDA toolkit (I'm on v8) and compute capability at least 2.0, in Visual Studio, go to Project Properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Common , find "Generate Relocatable Device Code" in the list, set it to "Yes (-rdc=true)".

For command line [this page](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/) suggests `–dc` compiler option

Answer (score 3):

Since CUDA 5.0, it is now possible to have externally defined data with CUDA, if separate compilation and linking is enabled. This blog post explains it: http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/

If this is done, one simply uses it like in the original post, and it 'just works'.